# Relationship between Parent and Child Instances

Tags: java, inheritance

I have started learning Java, I was asked this by a friend,

what is difference between

ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

*and*

ChildClass c = new ChildClass();

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `c` can make use of the things(methods, variables, enums, subclasses and so on. Naturally they have to be visible to the caller here) defined in `ChildClass`, while `p` can only acces contents of the `ParentClass` class.

Comment: visit this link for more https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Comment: @KevinEsche So does it mean ParentClass p = new ParentClass(); is same as that of ParentClass p = new ChildClass();

Comment: @Kimutai after looking at the link, i think what example suggests is exactly opposite of what _KevinEsche_ is saying because ParentClass Employee e is accessing method of Salary class(Child)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` will only have the methods accessible that are defined in `ParentClass` as long as it isn't casted to it's instance of `ChildClass`
`c` will have the methods available defined in `ParentClass` and the methods defined in `ChildClass`

For example:

```
class ParentClass {
   public void dothis() {
   }  
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
   public void doother() {
   }  
}
```

`p` will only be able to call `p.dothis()`. calling on `p.doother()` will result in an exception, or make your program fail to compile at all.

`c` will gladly accept `c.dothis()` and `c.doother()`

if you "suspect"(you can never know for sure without a check when programming) that an object might be a certain child class, you can attempt to downcast it.
Always check before doing so by checking the instance of the object.
When the check passes, you can **cast** the object to the child class.

```
if(p instanceof ChildClass) {
    ChildClass c = (ChildClass)p;
    c.doother();
}
```

Comment: inaccurate. c will not have access to ParentClass private methods. also, p can have accoess to ChildClass methods if explicitly cast

Comment: @sharonbn for sure they have to be visible and for sure you can cast it. If you include every other material connected to the topic, like access modifier and casting, your statment would be inaccurate aswell, because there is still the possiblity to use reflection..

Comment: of course it was inaccurate, thats why I was adding the extra explanation. But remember it's someone that's learning java. Making it too complicated at once loses the answer within the forest of possiblities.

Comment: calling on p.doother() will result in compiler error!!

Comment: method access modifiers is integral part of learning inheritence in Java IMO\

Comment: compiler error, exception, given where in the program flow/casting flow it's done sharon. be specific when the compiler error will occur will you?

Comment: i was using the same "specific" wording as "calling on p.doother()"

Comment: @Tschallacka i could get what you are saying but I saw an Example of [Runtime Polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) where ParentClass is able to access methods of ChildClass. Can you please explain me that in your answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @sharonbn i will keep in mind to learn access modifiers and experiment on accessing parent-child methods. Thanks.

Comment: @rdj that is because the mailcheck method exists in both. The childclass has overridden the parentsclass method. Ill try to add an excample that explains it better.

Comment: @Tschallacka experimented a bit, now clear with your explanation and polymorphism. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of binding 1)Early binding 2) Late binding 
Binding means comiler indetifiy the specify procedure call.
Method overloading is best example of early binding

While Run-time polymorphism is best example of late binding

```
class Parent{

    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    int a=100;
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Parent a =new Parent();
        a.test();
        Parent b=new Child();
        b.test();
 }
}
```

Above example may clear your concepts

Comment: so basically Parent b = new Child(); and Child c = new Child(); would refer to same method ie test() in Child. Then what is the difference between these two ? Thanks. @KevalPithva